# How to decrypt Cryptcat (twofish) data?

Tags: encryption, nc

I have some packets that are encrypted with Cryptcat tool and I want to decrypt them. I have the encryption password. I tried to use netcat with cryptcat, but every time I'm connecting from netcat to cryptcat and try to send something the connection closes.

I tried the following:

```
cryptcat -vv -k p@ssword -l -p 1337 > decryptedfile
```

and from another terminal:

```
cat encrypted | nc localhost 1337
```

When I hit enter the connection closes!

Comment: For other reason than reaching the end of file? Was anything written? Does sending work if you use `cryptcat` instead `nc` to send the data (and why aren't you using `cryptcat` for sending)?

Comment: Are you sure you've not got your decrypted content in `decryptedfile`?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. Note that encryption and decryption are paired on the basis that sending encrypts and receiving decrypts. (You can't use `cryptcat` to send an encrypted file in order to decrypt it.)

You might want to check that your encrypted source file contains plausible data (i.e. it's non-zero length), and using `tshark` or an equivalent check that the data really is transmitted across the wire.

***First, generate an encrypted file***

We start listening on System 2 before we transmit the message on System 1.

**System 2**

```
nc -vv -l -p 1337 >message.enc

hex message.enc
   0000 14 fd 25 da c3 5e 36 81  b2 7b e7 b0 13 4b b5 8b  ..%..^6. .{...K..
   0010 cc 13 4c 60 bd 54 1e e2  5b 01 7f ac bc 93 27 6b  ..L`.T.. [.....'k
   0020 c3 a3 90 30 44 76 e1 61  f5 42 2d 04 f2 13 eb d4  ...0Dv.a .B-.....
   0030 9c d9 9c 75 95 10 b2 55  42 bf 0d cb cb           ...u...U B....
```

**System 1**

```
date | cryptcat -vv -k p@ssword -w 1 system2 1337
```

***Now, resend the encrypted file***

As before, we start listening on the receiver before transmitting the message

**System 1**

```
cryptcat -vv -k p@ssword -l -p 1337    # → Thu 25 Oct 15:07:24 BST 2018
```

**System 2**

```
nc -vv -w 1 system1 1337 <message.enc
```

---

***Alternative recommendation***

In general terms, the original author of `netcat` stated that they preferred to keep it purely as a network tool, and for encryption to be added using external tools. Taking this approach one could use `mcrypt` and build a pair of tool chains like this:

```
generate_data | mcrypt -z | nc ...

... nc -l | mcrypt -d -z | produce_data
```

An advantage here is that standalone decryption is possible, and does not require using `nc` ... `cryptcat -l` between two servers. It also decouples the direction of the transfer from the implied encryption or decryption of the message.